# WordPress on WP7

Tags: mobile

Is there an app for the Windows Phone (7) that allows submission to WordPress?

Having used the WordPress app on the Blackberry, I'm looking for one that is similar to that, but for the WP7.

I've had a look and not found anything, though there are rumours (potentially unsubstantiated) that one is being created..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official page: http://windowsphone.wordpress.org/

Was kinda hard to find, I basically guessed URL in few tries in analogy to android.wordpress.org :)

Comment: and in case you want the zune link to install it, it's this: zune://navigate/?appID=5f64ad85-f801-e011-9264-00237de2db9e

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they may be working on one, but no hard dates yet:

[Speculative blog post.](http://www.blogherald.com/2010/11/29/wordpress-quietly-creating-windows-phone-7-app/)

[Forums post by a member of the mobile team.](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/wordpress-for-windows-phone-7#post-530036)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was just being too eager!.

It's now available for download. See here:

http://www.redmondpie.com/wordpress-for-windows-phone-7-is-now-available-for-download/

Answer (score 0):

Official announcement http://en.blog.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/wordpress-for-windows-phone-7/